# sql counting all records belong to parent record with many to may relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Tables called **Category** and **Posts**. a Post can be *belong to more than one* category. A category has many posts and their relationship is **many to many**. i created a new weak entity *cat_post* table. in **Category**, a record can have many child but not a child of child. so i want to count all posts belongs to all parent records.

Category table fields

```
id    category_id
1
2
3       
4       1
5       1
6       2
7       2
```

Posts table

```
id 
1
2
3
```

cat_post table field

```
tender_id   category_id
1               4
2               5
3               3
3               5
4               6
4               4
```

Category:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| category_id     | int(11)      | NO   | NULL | NULL   |      NULL      |  
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Posts:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------+  
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra     |  
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------+  
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |           |  
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------+
```

cat_post:

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |  
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| category_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |  
| post_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |  
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

i want to count all posts that belongs to parent records. in other word count all posts to each parent record of a category where category.category_id is null only.
**NB**: if a category record has a child then there will be no post to that record.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this would work for your requirement:
(In my example *tender_id* is named *post_id*)

```
SELECT c.id, count(p.id) as postcount 
FROM Category AS c
INNER JOIN cat_post AS cp ON c.id = cp.category_id 
INNER JOIN Posts AS p ON p.id = cp.post_id
WHERE c.category_id is null
GROUP BY c.id
```

This will join all tables and only select those records that are *parent* (no category_id in categories). Then it groups the result by category.id, and count every post for each category.

Here is an [example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52cbe/2).

Answer (score 0):

You should connect CATEGORY table with it self to count also `Categories` even with 0 children. Then connect `cat_post` table in the Join I used `OR` to handle the case when main category has no children. Also if you want to count only DISTINCT posts for each category use COUNT(DISTINCT) (For instance if one post belongs to two different children of one parent category then should you count it as one or two ?)

```
SELECT A.Id, COUNT(DISTINCT cat_post.Post_Id) FROM Category A
LEFT JOIN Category B on A.Id=B.Category_id
LEFT JOIN cat_post ON (cat_post.category_id = B.Id) 
                      or 
                      (cat_post.category_id = A.Id)
WHERE A.Category_Id is NULL
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: dear Valex for the question you raise i want to count as two since the parent should be the sum of all child records.  (For instance if one post belongs to two different children of one parent category then should you count it as one or two ?). i'm referring to this scenario

Comment: @GirmangusHailu In this case you should use this query without the `DISTINCT` keyword.